# Failing to get the same base 64 modulus from two different sources

Tags: encoding, base64, rsa, padding

Good evening everyone,

I'm having a bit of a problem with base64 encoding
Im generating a private and publickey using RSA , and my Public key returns something like this :

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
    MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA4iv0NO5KZaJbHakBH5KIl5UyLWPRObsz
    qfA6gSLF/i4cqBRGQVJYkDAvSav2RzO3jDImcdWLWuqZauRFzqrWsAC2qV9bBHhrMmesw2/qYLUq
    Iq7ufnjxm5u/cI0KDyLO9NE+U5utyHoTdx5uXv4OVueqiD06ehnIQJrJYyAinEJimgtBRkK5ChZC
    OtSjPAwcPNJU9tUeMXkUkkwsQf4H9fIT9+HbIxofHAS0iLTBKzuF+CVvFwFoYeaF9tUXy1hlVtcW
    ILJv8TDMSa0KgCxud63IetKyjG01mzvQ95pCrHE/qBPIqvFVmVO7xBW62DoYeRNVcgiHzEV7iKEo
    RqwAlQIDAQAB
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Using that Public key , i retreive this Modulus using the `GetModulus` function

```
AOIr9DTuSmWiWx2pAR+SiJeVMi1j0Tm7M6nwOoEixf4uHKgURkFSWJAwL0mr9kczt4wyJnHVi1rq
mWrkRc6q1rAAtqlfWwR4azJnrMNv6mC1KiKu7n548Zubv3CNCg8izvTRPlObrch6E3cebl7+Dlbn
qog9OnoZyECayWMgIpxCYpoLQUZCuQoWQjrUozwMHDzSVPbVHjF5FJJMLEH+B/XyE/fh2yMaHxwE
tIi0wSs7hfglbxcBaGHmhfbVF8tYZVbXFiCyb/EwzEmtCoAsbnetyHrSsoxtNZs70PeaQqxxP6gT
yKrxVZlTu8QVutg6GHkTVXIIh8xFe4ihKEasAJU=
```

But when i use a website Like https://superdry.apphb.com/tools/online-rsa-key-converter
the Modulus returns something like this

```
4iv0NO5KZaJbHakBH5KIl5UyLWPRObszqfA6gSLF/i4cqBRGQVJYkDAvSav2RzO3jDImcdWLWuqZauRFzqrWsAC2qV9bBHhrMmesw2/qYLUqIq7ufnjxm5u/cI0KDyLO9NE+U5utyHoTdx5uXv4OVueqiD06ehnIQJrJYyAinEJimgtBRkK5ChZCOtSjPAwcPNJU9tUeMXkUkkwsQf4H9fIT9+HbIxofHAS0iLTBKzuF+CVvFwFoYeaF9tUXy1hlVtcWILJv8TDMSa0KgCxud63IetKyjG01mzvQ95pCrHE/qBPIqvFVmVO7xBW62DoYeRNVcgiHzEV7iKEoRqwAlQ==
```

My question is , How can i make my modulus look like the second in java (i need it in that format for encryption) ? is it a padding thing ? if any one can help that would be great

Comment: *...i retreive this Modulus using the GetModulus function* What GetModulus function? *How can i make my modulus look like the second in java...* you have shown *any* code as to how you obtained the first value. The first value does include a leading 0 byte, so if you remove that and then base64 encode what's left then you'll get the second value.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thank you , removing leading 0 worked perfectly , if i may ask , how did you know that i have a leading 0 by just looking at the first value ?

Comment: When I decoded the first value I noticed it was 257 bytes and the second decoded to 256 bytes. Just examining the bytes it was obvious was the problem was.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk that's amazing! very good observation, thank you again !  what did you decode it to? just for my own edification.

Comment: In python I just used `base64.b64decode()`